# Some 32-bit dlls won't register on Win 7 from VS 2013-created installer

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, registration, installshield-le

I have a VS setup project to create an installer from an MS Access database and a large number of dlls and ocxs, mostly 32-bit. I am using VS 2013 with Installshield LE. An old version of the installer (perhaps created with an earlier version of VS) works OK. Although the Installshield project places the dlls in [WindowsFolder]/System32, they appear in c:\Window\sysWOW64, which I think is how 32-bit dlls should be treated.

However, when I rebuild the installer in VS 2013 with some updates for the MSAccess database and changed install directory, 23 of the 57 dlls and ocxs fail to register, when running the installer on Win 7 (64 bit) with the message Module Error 1904 Failed to Register HRESULT-2147220473.

The dlls and OCXs which fail to register do not show any systematic differences from those which do register. Can anyone suggest what might be causing these dlls and ocxs not to register?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the setup project to place all the 57 dlls, ocxs and .exe in the Windows Predefined folder in InstallShield LE Project Assistant, Application Files tab the project installs OK. I had defined a new folder as Windows/System32 and it was having all the dlls and ocxs in there that caused the problem